# Route IP from one vlan to another vlan in the same vrf of the same router

Tags: networking, routing, cisco-vpn, mpls

Can you route a IP (/32) from one vlan to another vlan in the same vrf of the same router ?

Exemple:

```
example_router#show version
Cisco IOS Software, c7600s72033_rp Software (c7600s72033_rp-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.2(33)SRD6, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)

example_router(config)#ip route vrf EXAMPLE 10.10.10.3 255.255.255.255 vlan 2706
% For VPN or topology routes, must specify a next hop IP address if not a point-to-point interface
example_router(config)#
example_router(config)#ip route vrf EXAMPLE 10.10.10.3 255.255.255.255 vlan 2706 10.10.20.1
%Invalid next hop address (it's this router)

example_router#sh run in vlan 2705
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 339 bytes
!
interface Vlan2705
 ip vrf forwarding EXAMPLE
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.0.0.1
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 load-interval 30
 no clns route-cache
end

example_router#sh run in vlan 2706
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 339 bytes
!
interface Vlan2706
 ip vrf forwarding EXAMPLE
 ip address 10.10.20.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.0.0.1
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 load-interval 30
 no clns route-cache
end
```

vrf config (requested by @rnxrx):

```
example_router#show vrf EXAMPLE
    Name                             Default RD         Protocols   Interfaces
    EXAMPLE                          xxxxxx:yyyyyy      ipv4        Vl2705
                                                                    Vl2706
[output removed]

example_router#show running-config vrf EXAMPLE
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 7992 bytes
ip vrf EXAMPLE
 description mpls_vpn_EXAMPLE
 rd xxxxxx:yyyyyy
 route-target export xxxxxx:zzzzzz
 route-target import xxxxxx:yyyyyy
!
    [output removed]

!
router bgp xxxxxx
 !
 address-family ipv4 vrf EXAMPLE
  no synchronization
  redistribute connected
 exit-address-family
!
end
```

I need to break an old vlan in 2, and 1 equipment needs to be on the second vlan, I need to temporary make it run until a client can remotely connect to change it's IP address.

If not, the only option I see is to syncronize with the client and configure the subnet (10.10.10.1/24 in exemple) on the second vlan for a few minutes.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please post the physical interfaces configurations with their description?

Comment: @petrus - Both vlan's are on the same physical interface, where an GPON/OLT is connected via trunk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this is valid, and actually pretty common.  The router will treat these interfaces (and associated routes) as being part of a common routing/forwarding table which will be kept separate from any others (unless you manually cross-import).

Comment: Thank you, can you give an example of command to route them, if you look at the example I gave, the commands I tried failed (as a workaround I used just one vlan and raised both IP classes on it until all clients have changed their IP and them break them in 2 again :) ).

Comment: Do you have a global definition of the vrf elsewhere in the config?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the example.